# Is $f(K, f(K, x))$ a pseudorandom function?

Tags: pseudo-random-function, pseudo-random-permutation

Given a PRF $f : \{0, 1\}^n \times \{0, 1\}^n \rightarrow \{0, 1\}^n$, is $f(K, f(K, x))$ a PRF, too?

My hunch is to construct a PRP similar to Feistel ciphers but with the property $f(K, f(K, x)) = x$, and disprove the statement with PRP/PRF switching lemma. However, I haven't found a concrete instance with the desired properties above yet.

Can anyone share some hints? Thanks!

Comment: This construction is a PRF with advantage roughly $q^2/2^n$ + PRF-Adv.

Comment: Feistel ciphers do not fit the description $f(K, f(K, x)) = x$ directly ...

Comment: I'm now confused by your question. Are you asking whether for a general PRF $f$ whether $f(K,f(K,x))$ is a PRF? (to which the answer is yes) Are you asking whether there exists a PRF / PRP $f$ such that for all keys and values $f(K,f(K,x))=x$ but $f$ itself is a PRF / PRP? (to which the answer is no) Or is it something else?

Comment: A PRP with the property $f(K, f(K,x)) = x$ isn't a PRP. This is because you can trivially distinguish it from a random permutation by checking the equality $f(K, f(K, x)) = x$ on a few random points. More specifically, a permutation with the property you describe is called an *involution*, which is a proper subset of the set of all permutations. Querying the equation on some number of randomly chosen $x$ is simply an efficient (probabilistic) construction for testing membership in the subset of all involutions (the particular number you query it on probably matters, but not for your purpose).

Comment: Generically you shouldn't hope to construct some (pseudo-random object) with some easily checkable structure, because checking that structure becomes an efficient distinguishing test for distinguishing your object from random. I believe this is related to the concept of "natural proofs" in complexity theory, but don't have a great understanding of that concept.

Comment: This looks like a PRF though. Consider that $f_K$ is a PRF, but $F_k = f_K\circ f_K$ isn't. This means that there's some adversary $A$ that distinguishes $F_k$ from random. Then, an adversary $B$ against $f_k$ can simulate $A$, and can simulate $A$'s oracle $F_k$ via its oracle to $f_k$ (just by computing $f_k\circ f_k). This intuitive argument doesn't work out the precise advantage, but it makes it seem like your statement is probably true.

Comment: Mark and SEJPM, thank you very much. It reminds me that Prof. Dan Boneh referred to a similar argument in his crypto OCW. Now I see my hunch is wrong :)

However, I've also tried to prove the statement before in the way @Mark suggests. It ended up stuck at the problem "If the oracle accessed by $B$ is truly random, how  to prove the oracle $B$ constructs for $A$ is truly random, too?"

I'd like to know if a solution to (or a construction which avoids) this problem exists. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm responding to:

> "If the oracle accessed by B is truly random, how to prove the oracle B constructs for A is truly random, too?" I'd like to know if a solution to (or a construction which avoids) this problem exists.

This is a "good" thing to get stuck on, because it's not something you can just push under the rug.
Concretely, let $f_k(\cdot)$ be a random function, so for any $x_i$, you have that $y_i = f_k(x_i)$ is uniformly random (and independent of any other $y_j$).
If we knew that $z_i = f_k(y_i)$ was *also* uniformly random, and independent of all other $z_j$'s, we'd be done!

Is this the case? The answer is *almost*. Specifically, provided that $\forall i : y_i\neq y_j$, it shouldn't be hard to prove that all of the $z_i$'s are uniformly random (and *independent*), so everything works out well.

Intuitively, a random function can be expressed as a lookup table (and this is the most compact way to express it), so to compute $f_k(0)$ we lookup some value $U_0$.
The entries in this table are uniformly random, independent variables.
We can think about using this lookup table for $f_k$ to compute $f_k\circ f_k$ by doing two lookups (so precisely the way you'd expect to).

Now consider computing $q$ values $((f_k\circ f_k)(1),\dots, (f_k\circ f_k)(q))$.
This will all be uniformly random values, but there's a risk there's some dependence between them.
Specifically, if $f_k(i) = f_k(j)$ for $i\neq j$, then we'll have that $(f_k\circ f_k)(i) = (f_k\circ f_k)(j)$, so the random variables $(f_k\circ f_k)(i)$ and $(f_k\circ f_k)(j)$ will be *correlated* (and therefore not independent).
In terms of our lookup table analogy, the event $f_k(i) = f_k(j)$ happening means that our lookup table for $f_k\circ f_k$ ends up having $i$ and $j$ point to the same "slot" in the lookup table for $f_k$, which is the cause of the problem.

So, we want to bound the probability $\Pr[\exists (i,j)\in[q]^2\setminus\{(i,i)\mid i\in[q]\} : f_k(i) = f_k(j)]$.
This can be done with the *birthday bound* (which you should look up if you're not familiar with it), and can be upper bounded by $q^2/2^n$, which is where the term that was mentioned in the comments comes from.

Comment: Thank you very much, Mark! I didn't notice that to an oracle adv. I/O relation is everything. If the results of distinct queries seem to follow independent uniform distributions, there is no way for the adv. to distinguish the function from a truly random one. I only paid attention to the "function" part and totally forgot the "observation" part. Thanks for your great answer!

Comment: How does this austerely lead to a mathematical proof of PRF-property of $f(K,f(K,x))$? I can see the intuition, but not how this would lead to a totally formal proof.