# Why this isn't a secure PRF?

Tags: encryption, cryptanalysis, pseudo-random-function

Given that F is a secure PRF in the example $$F'(k,x)= F(k,x)\mathbin\|F(k,F(k,x))$$ I'm not sure why this isn't a secure PRF? Under what condition $F(k, F(k,x))$ when concatenated to $F(k,x)$ the adversary will be able to distinguish between $F'$ and true random function?

Comment: What happens if a second query to F can depend on the output of a first query? How would this allow you to break this?

Comment: A related question [Is $f(K, f(K, x))$ a pseudorandom function?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/72229/18298)

Comment: What's the relationship between input/output domains of $F$ for the definition to make sense? Then what's $F'$ input/output domains? Now assume you have a black box that implements $F'$ for a fixed unknown $k$, and made a  first query with some $x$ of $\ell\gg1$ bits, and got some answer $y$. How do you craft the second query to confirm beyond reasonable doubt that the blackbox implements $F'$? Note: the question is easier than for $F(k,F(k,x))$.

Comment: Thanks for the inputs. My problem here is I'm unable to understand what should be the output of $F(k, F(k,x))$. I went through PRF tutorial on [Coursera](https://www.coursera.org/learn/crypto/lecture/9p25F/review-prps-and-prfs) by Dan and he says that PRF given input K, X -> Y. When I give this Y as an input to the outer F what does it output? I'm just confused :(

Comment: @Alex: $F(k,F(k,x))$ is $z$ that you get when you 1) feed $x$ to an oracle implementing function $F$ for fixed unknown $k$, yielding $y$ 2) take $y$ and feed it to the oracle again, yielding $z$.

Comment: @fgrieu I think in my mind I'm getting confused between this and PRG.. In PRG we call it secure when the output is indistinguishable from an uniformly random string. In PRF we call it secure if the function is indistinguishable from Func(K,M).. In this case even if I append z at the end shouldn't the overall concatenated string remain random as if obtained from a random function?

Comment: If I use the output of $F(k,x)$ obtained in first step for a fixed $k$ in the next query I can distinguish between $F′$ from $random function$ with more than negligible probability?

Comment: @Alex: you are on good tracks, but you need to reformulate that in the framework of an attack/adversary/algorithm in a position to use an oracle/block box/API that (sometime) implements $F'$ _without giving a direct access to $F$_, since the question is about $F'$ being a PRF. That oracle/block box/API is assumed to sometime use, in the manner defined by $F'(k,x)= F(k,x)\mathbin\|F(k,F(k,x))$, a sub-oracle/block box/API implementing $F$; and sometime implement a true PRF. The goal of the attack/adversary/algorithm is to _distinguish_ between the two cases.

Comment: @fgrieu Sorry I got busy on other stuff so didn't get chance to get back on this! Based on what I read PRF is a deterministic function which means that every time I give it input x it will give same output y for fixed key k. So, if I input some $x$ in Step 1 the output will be $y||z$ where $y$ is the output of $F(k,x)$ and z is the O/P of $F(k,F(k,x)$. In second step if I input y then the output should be $z||w$.. So its easy to identify the pattern here which is not likely for true random function? Is my interpretation correct?

Comment: @Alex: Yes, you got it. Depending on the academic context, this is a correct answer; or it needs more formalization, like: stating what you described as an algorithm, called the _distinguisher_, invoking $F'$ as a sub-function, producing an output 1 if it concludes $F'$ is of the form $F(k,x)\mathbin\|F(k,F(k,x))$; computing the (or a minimum) _advantage_ of that distinguisher w.r.t. an algorithm that outputs 1 or 0 at random, and show that it is non-vanishing when the parameter controlling the width of things increases. You could do this and make an answer out of it.